# Passing Xpath in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, dom, random

I am trying to insert xml elements into an xml file using XSLT. I have two files, input file that contains the xpaths (ex: /root/element ) and depending on the input xpath I insert the element into the output file, for example if the input element value is /root/element then I should insert new_element into that destination so the output will be

```
<root>
  <new_element id="1">some content</new_element>
  <element>some content</element>
</root>
```

I am populating a variable with the xpath input and then using the variable, but I am getting an error message "parameters and variables can not be used in patterns). Here is the part where I am using the variable:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I am very new to XSLT so I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or if my logic to do is not appropriate.

I will appreciate your help :)

Thanks

Comment: A sample of what you have currently and what results you might be expecting always helps :)

Comment: I edited your post to make the code samples visible but I don't see any variable use in the second sample. So please make sure you show us all the details to enable us to understand the problem.

Comment: I built a program that gets the xpaths file and generate the appropriate xslt script. Now, I am having a problem with the namespaces, so, I am using xmlspy to debug the script and run it.. XMLSPY doesn't objects over the name spaces which I am getting them in the input and they are correct! so I tried to run it without the namespaces but it skips the pattern that I specified and doesn't add anything to the destination element that is specified in the XPATH provided.

Comment: Here is a sample the code that I generated.. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?altova_samplexml C:\Users\FShlash\Desktop\1.out.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/root/content">
<xsl:copy>
<flag sender="me" recipient="you" issueDateTime="02/14/2011">
<flagSubject> Error </flagSubject>
<message>
<p>r5 Designator Text is empty</p>
</message>
</flag>

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*| node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
Thank you verymuch for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, variables cannot be used in *match patterns*. Match patterns are the expressions you suplly to an `<xsl:template match="...">`. You have to use literals in those cases. Consider that the templates are compiled before they are executed, so having a variable in the compiled expression could make it perform less well.

If you're new to XSLT and have an interest in learning it, there are a couple good resources on the net (start with [Jeni Tennison's website](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/), as well as in printed form.

Comment: Thanks Lumi, so what do you suggest if I want to pass the xpath and use it to insert xml element?

Comment: Either, put the paths into your XSLT file instead of listing them separately (most sensible), or write a cool build system to generate your XSLT file using XSLT — it's just an XML document after all!

Comment: Thanks Nicolas.. I can't list the paths in the XSLT because they are dynamicly generated.. Though, I can build a system to generate the XSLT depending on the input file, but the problem with that I will have to do another stage.. so what I am trying to do is within the same stage (project) I generate the input xml that contain the paths and then insert the elements depending on the given path.. if I generate the XSLT I will not be able to call it in the same project I will have to create another project to do that then run this project after generating the XSLT script.